# How to add or adjust this code to ALSO listen for browser resizing?

Tags: javascript

The following code does what I need on my site:

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".position").css("height", $(".wrapper-slider").height());
});`

It makes my position div the same height as the wrapper-slider.

However, if I change the window size, it doesn't retrigger the sizing that that this javascript does.

I thought maybe adding lines something like this would work:

`$( window ).resize(function() {
  $(".position").css("height", $(".wrapper-slider").height()); 
});`

However, it doesn't.  I have to manually click Reload or Refresh on my browser to have the resizing triggered. What am I missing?

If helpful, this was the original inspiration: http://jsfiddle.net/Jyu94/

It looks like I could use this too:

`$(window).resize(function(){
    location.reload();}
    );`

I'm not sure how to combine the two so that its all one command.

Comment: Please include the code that you used to attempt this. SO is not a free code service.

Comment: Can you please update your post to be a [better question](/help/how-to-ask) so people can actually help solve it? Remember that the only information people can respond to is what you put in your post, and this one needs more information.

Comment: Per your suggestions, I've rewritten the question to hopefully be clearer about what I've tried and what I'm needing assistance on. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried adding `+ "px"` to `$(".wrapper-slider").height()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to add `+ "px"` after getting the height of `.wrapper-slider` div! Here's an example (run it in Full Page so you can resize):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var new_height = $(".wrapper-slider").height() + "px";
  $(".position").css("height", new_height); // SET HEIGHT

  $(".position .dim").text(new_height); // DISPLAY NEW HEIGHT
  $(".wrapper-slider .dim").text(new_height); // DISPLAY NEW HEIGHT
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  var new_height = $(".wrapper-slider").height() + "px";
  $(".position").css("height", new_height); // SET HEIGHT

  $(".position .dim").text(new_height); // DISPLAY NEW HEIGHT
  $(".wrapper-slider .dim").text(new_height); // DISPLAY NEW HEIGHT
});
```

```css
/* MOST OF THE STYLING HERE IS PURELY AESTHETIC AND DOES NOT AFFECT ANSWER :) */ 

div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45vw;
  min-width: auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.position {
  background-color: #d55;
  height: 75px; // NOTE THAT THE JS CODE OVERRIDES THIS
}
.wrapper-slider {
  background-color: #da1;
  height: 50vh;
}
.class {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dim, .class {
   font-family: "Courier"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position">
<span class="class">.position</span>
<p class="dim"></p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-slider">
<span class="class">.wrapper-slider</span>
<p class="dim"></p>
</div>
```